# How do projects work differently than solutions

Tags: visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions, solution

I a have a Visual Studio 2015 Solution "S1" and in it contains one project "DAL".  If I open the solution in VS it opens correctly, and all of my references are known.  I can add a second Project to solution "S1" called "Model".  Once again both "DAL" and "Model" work, build, execute, and all references are known.

If however I open a solution "S2" and in it contains the project "Model", and then I add an existing project "DAL", all of my references are unknown.  All of them.  System, System.Core, System.Data, EntityFramework, and the list goes on.  If I remove the reference, save, and re-add the reference it is immediately unknown.

I have also tried to open "DAL" from its project file, and again the references are unknown.  I have made sure that both projects are using the same version of the .NET Framework (4.5.2), and that both have the same Platform Target.

There is only one difference that I have found is that in the unknown references the Path property is blank and in the known reference it has C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.dll, which of course makes sense because the reference was found.

I just don't understand how if I open a project by its project file I have no references, but if I open the Solution I have references.

Comment: Did you install all the updates?

Comment: No, I just finished installing the SSDT updates, and the Web Tools updates with no luck.  Then it told me to update version of VS.  I had community running, and updated it to Enterprise.  Low and behold.  It works.  Not sure why, unless it corrected some Env Variables, but it works.  So thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, so I spoke to soon.  While upgrading to VS 2015 Enterprise did fix my missing References when opening "DAL" by the project file and the solution file.  If I add it as an existing project to another solution it is still showing all my references in "DAL" as missing.  Not the ones in the other project.

Comment: Update to Enterprise was not needed. Just ensure you have installed all Visual Studio updates. If you use a project in an other solution you also have to add all dependent projects. Clean and rebuild afterwards.

Comment: I have all the updates, and have done a clean, but it will not rebuild, because as I said none of the references are found.  Not System, System.Core, System.Windows.Forms, none of them.  There are no dependant projects for this project I'm trying to add to and existing solution.  Again if I open the Project or Solution on its own it works fine.  But if I try to add it as an existing project to another project then none of the references are found.  I am going to try and create a new project and solution, and add all of the files into the new project and see if I still have problems.